# Delimit the string as per fixed width

Tags: excel, vba

I'm analyzing some data from logs file generated and right now it's formatted like this within a single cell in Excel, for example:

```
VER_OPS_A28.11.2019WQERTIU                                       29.04.2015                       0JAMEISON,PARK                95130901A-DEPT-S
VER_OPS_U30.12.2019QSPLABT                                       29.04.2015                       0TABIAS,MARTIEN               95130901A-DEPT-S
VER_OPS_U30.12.2020LKQPOHM                                       29.04.2015                       0Mathiaes                     1538  I-GL-P
```

All of the data is right now located in A column.

Now I want the output data in the following format in the excel sheet.

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VER_OPS_A | 28.11.2019 | WQERTIU | 29.04.2015 | 0 | JAMEISON,PARK | 95130901 | A-DEPT-S |
| VER_OPS_U | 30.12.2019 | QSPLABT | 29.04.2015 | 0 | TABIAS,MARTIEN | 95130901 | A-DEPT-S |
| VER_OPS_U | 30.12.2020 | LKQPOHM | 29.04.2015 | 0 | Mathiaes | 95130901 | I-GL-P |

I wanted to put the logic of string length in this case. But String length logic will not apply over here as you can see the string lengths are not uniform.
P.S: I have found another logic to apply. I have pasted the raw data in notepad++ and note down the column number (Column number can be seen in the right below section in the notepad++; if you move the cursor after desired string you want in a column). Now I manually take this column numbers and manually upload the file through power query.
Steps: Data>>From Text /CSV>> then select the raw data file in txt form>> then delimiter section put the column numbers like e.g. 0,9,19,26,75,99,112,136,144 for fixed width[For the given raw data] and Finish.
Desired result is getting appeared.
But want to know if we can incorporate this Column number from notepad++ into our vb code so that we can split the data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You've tagged the question with VBA so please post the code you got, where are you stuck and what errors are you getting.

Comment: I was unable to write the code as I don't know how to put this logic in vba. If you at least can give me an approach to apply the logic mentioned, it will be helpful.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns: my first attempt with VBA always consists of recording a macro and see what it looks like, but in this case there is indeed nothing useful (the settings, set in the text import wizard, are not recorded in VBA).

Answer (score 0):

You said you are already using Power Query for this, here is how you would do it in Power Query:

Split your first 5 columns by Positions 0,9,19,26,75,99

Split the next column by Delimter (space, left-most delimiter)

Split the last column by Digit to Non Digit

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Positions" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 9, 19, 26, 75, 99})),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Positions", "Column1.6", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false)),
    #"Split Column by Character Transition" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Split Column by Delimiter", "Column1.6.2", Splitter.SplitTextByCharacterTransition({"0".."9"}, (c) => not List.Contains({"0".."9"}, c)))
in
    #"Split Column by Character Transition"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This will work as a UDF:

```vb
Function FixedSplit(v, arr)
    Dim arrOut(), i As Long, ub As Long, s, pos As Long
    
    ub = UBound(arr)
    ReDim arrOut(1 To ub)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        pos = arr(i)
        If pos <= Len(v) Then
            If i < UBound(arr) Then
                s = Mid(v, pos, arr(i + 1) - pos)
            Else
                s = Mid(v, pos, Len(v)) 'reads to end of input
            End If
        Else
            s = ""
        End If
        arrOut(i) = Trim(s) 'remove any extra spaces
    Next i
    FixedSplit = arrOut
End Function
```

Example usage:
`=FixedSplit(A2,{1,66,99,100,129,137})`